# Unable to delete pictures ON jQuery File Upload Demo

Tags: php, jquery, xampp

Hello I checked the [System jQuery File Upload Demo](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) ON windows 7 IN XAMPP

And everything is working well I can upload images and delete

But IN Linux server I can not delete pictures What could be the problem

Comment: Since Linux is Case Sensitive and windows is not, your problem is probably a case issue, though it could also be a file path issue due to the two different file systems handling file paths differently.

Comment: Here is a small section of the code
from file UploadHandler.php line 37-44




    function __construct($options = null, $initialize = true) {
        $this->options = array(
            'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/',
            'upload_dir' => dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/files/',
            'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/files/',
            'user_dirs' => false,
            'mkdir_mode' => 0755,
            'param_name' => 'files',
   
   
   
   
   I need to list all folder path?

Comment: I don't know. First **you** need to figure out why it isn't working. Is it not finding the file?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem could be that your server does not support `DELETE` requests.

Go to `UploadHandler.php`, in the line `'delete_type' => 'DELETE'`, change it to `'delete_type' => 'POST'`.